# uri field in cognitive search custom skill interface

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

Can some one help me out with what the uri field represents , my guess is that it is the uri for the custom skill . [The link for the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-interface#consuming-custom-skills-from-skillset)

Comment: That's the uri of your Web API providing skills

Answer (score 0):

If you are choosing to use a custom skill, it is expected that you already have that custom skill live and accessible through a web API. The URI field allow Cognitive Search to know where to send the augmentation request. The URI should represent the endpoint of your custom skill.

If you do not have a custom skill, and would rather use one of the predefined and readily available cognitive skills such as key phrases extraction or image analysis skills, you can take a look at the [predefined data extraction documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-predefined-skills)